# Antonym of withholding the seal of approval

Tags: antonyms

Sources usually speak of "giving the seal of approval" to a product, program, etc. Is there an more literal but still idiomatic way of expressing the opposite of "withholding the seal of approval"?  I was thinking of "appending" or "affixing" but this seems to lack umph.

Answer (score 1):

Consider *applying*.

> **apply** *verb*
>   with object Put or spread (a substance) on a surface.
>   ‘the sealer can be applied to new wood’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/apply)

Here's an example of its use (it's a chapter subtitle):

- THE CERTIFIER: Applying the Seal of Approval
  [- The Middleman Economy by Marina Krakovsky](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=1cMYDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA47&lpg=PA47&dq=%22applying%20the%20seal%20of%20approval%22&source=bl&ots=WfykcdkiSp&sig=a6R-LL1ZINNM-0y7h-6g-lHDZTU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjB4u7bhNLYAhUG7WMKHa54BH0Q6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22applying%20the%20seal%20of%20approval%22&f=false)

The literal meaning is that the label is pasted onto product. The figurative meaning is that the certifier approves of the product.

Comment: Very nice application.

Comment: I'd consider forgetting 'applying'. [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gave+the+seal+of+approval%2Capplied+the+seal+of+approval%2C&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgave%20the%20seal%20of%20approval%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The OP wanted something more literal than 'giving'.